# Why is my PHP else not Showing?

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know why this code is not working it will display the Unfollow bit but not the follow part. all it should do is say follow if they are not following that person and unfollow if they are. I have tried using Just `if(row['following'])` But it has the same output.
Thanks

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","Password","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
session_start();
$follower=$_SESSION['user']['id'];
$following=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM following WHERE follower='$follower' AND following='$following'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if(isset($row['following'])){
?>
<a href="/profile/unfollow.php/?id=<?php echo $dnn['id']; ?>">
<?php
echo'<div id="button">';
echo'Unfollow <?php echo $dnn["username"]; ?>';
echo'</div>';
}
else{
?>
<a href="/profile/follow.php/?id=<?php echo $dnn['id']; ?>">
<?php
echo'<div id="button">';
echo'Follow <?php echo $dnn["username"]; ?>';
echo'</div>';
}


mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Add `var_dump($row['following']);` in your `while` loop and post results.

Comment: Just in case of using this code on working website: You put a GET value directly in SQL command. DANGER!

Comment: `if(row['following'])` is probably too permissive an expression (thanks to PHP's type conversions and loose definition of "true"). I suggest changing it to `if( row['following'] === true ) {`.

Comment: are these necessary? `echo'Unfollow <?php echo $dnn["username"]; ?>';` and `echo'Follow <?php echo $dnn["username"]; ?>';`

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like `if($result->num_rows > 0){Unfollow}else{Follow}`?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 3):

`$row['following']` is always going to be set if that is a column in your table. What you want is to check to see if it has a value:

```
if(!empty($row['following'])){
```

FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: Hi, I have just Tried your answer but it has the same outcome

Comment: What does `var_dump($row);` show?

Comment: It also has the same outcome.

Comment: Post the results of it here. It contains info we need to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","Password","DB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

session_start();

$follower=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['user']['id']); /* ESCAPE STRING */
$following=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['id']); /* ESCAPE STRING */

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM following WHERE follower='$follower' AND following='$following'"); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

     if(!empty($row['following'])){ /* IF FOLLOWING IS NOT EMPTY */

     $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['id']);
     $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['username']);

     echo "<a href='profile/unfollow.php?id=$id'>";
     echo '<div id="button">';
     echo 'Unfollow '.$username;
     echo '</div>';

     } /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY FOLLOWING */

     else { /* ELSE IF EMPTY */

     $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['id']);
     $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['username']);

     echo "<a href='profile/follow.php?id=$id'>";
     echo '<div id="button">';
     echo 'Follow '.$username;
     echo '</div>';

     } /* END OF ELSE */

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */    

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

### Summary

- Moved the `mysqli_close($con)` outside the while loop. I'm pretty sure your loop would stop at the first cycle.
- What is **dnn[]** inside your while loop? Replaced it with **row[]**.
- Used **mysqli_real_escape_string** function to prevent some of the *SQL injections*
- Replaced the **isset()** function to **empty()** function
- More explanations quoted in /* */ given in the code above